# NGINX server is producing error response code 400 and "Bad Request" message when the server is rapidly requested

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ssl, asp.net, 400

The API serves as a proxy for M3U8 videos. While accessed through an HTTP connection at IP:port requests to the API never result in a response code 400. Despite being tested under semi heavy load(10 videos playing all at the same time), no issues have been encountered. However, when tested with nginx SSL + domain, frequent failed requests have been observed under a light load(one video playing). The logs reveal two errors:

- On 2023/02/03 18:32:38, there was a critical error in the SSL handshake, as indicated by the message "SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share)" and the client IP address "142.93.***".
- On 2023/02/03 18:34:12, there was a connection error with the upstream server, indicated by the message "connect() failed (111: Unknown error)" and the client IP address "616.231.*". This error occurred during a GET request for "/proxy/m3u8/.../index-v1-a1.m3u8" that was directed to the upstream server "proxy.vnxservers.com".

This api is made in asp.net, however the error isn't coming from the api itself, rather its coming from nginx.

Comment: `client IP address "616.231.*".` ... really?

Comment: http 400 is `the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error` ... so nginx is detecting an error in the request